# Get customers number of orders

Tags: nopcommerce

How can I get customer number of orders on customer order page on public store. I have seen that already exist on admin page bu is there any setting that should be activated as this can be shown on public store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the controller you are using has the `_storeContext`, `_workContext` and `_orderService` variables injected, this will do it:

```c#
var orderCount = _orderService.SearchOrders(
    storeId: _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id,
    customerId: _workContext.CurrentCustomer.Id)
    .Count();
```

If any of those variables don't exist, manually add them to your controller. Toy need to add the private variables:

```c#
private readonly IStoreContext _storeContext;
private readonly IOrderService _orderService;
private readonly IWorkContext _workContext;
```

Extend the constructor of the controller and add in the code to save the injected values:

```c#
public YourController(/* other parameters */
    IOrderService orderService, 
    IWorkContext workContext,
    IStoreContext storeContext)
{
    //snip
    this._orderService = orderService;
    this._shipmentService = shipmentService;
    this._workContext = workContext;
    this._storeContext = storeContext;
}
```